# Use Ionic components with an existing Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My goal is to be able to serve my Angular 8 application to both web and mobile in the future with a single code base.

Currently, I have an existing **Angular 8 project** that was created using Angular CLI.  To run it, I would enter ***`ng serve -o`*** from the command prompt. The web browser would launch with *`localhost:4200`*.

I do not know if it is possible to integrate the latest Ionic into my Angular 8 project without becoming an **Ionic Project**?  In other words, I do not want to enter ***"ionic serve"*** to start my existing Angular project, however, I would like to be able to take advantage of using the Ionic components within the Angular project.

If it is possible, would you be kind enough to provide 
step-by-step guidance?